# How do I get the picture to load on the same page instead of on a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three drop down menus and these generate a result depending on what is selected. When pressing the button "Show picture" it opens up the picture on a new page. I would like it to load on the same page.

```js
function f(){
    var gid=function(i){return document.getElementById(i);};
    var product_id=gid("one").value;
    var version_id=gid("two").value;
    var arch_id=gid("three").value;
    if(product_id==='default' || version_id ==='default' || arch_id === 'default'){return;}
    window.location.replace('images/' +product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.jpg');   
}
```

```html
<select id="one">
    <option value="value-a1">string1</option>
    <option value="value-a2">string2</option>
    <option value="value-a3">string3</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
    <option value="value-b4">string4</option>
    <option value="value-b5">string5</option>
    <option value="value-b6">string6</option>
</select>

<select id="three">
    <option value="value-c6">string7</option>
    <option value="value-c7">string8</option>
    <option value="value-c8">string9</option>
</select>
<input onclick="Javascript:f();" value="Show picture" type="button"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty `<img></img>` tag, and use this **JQuery** function to alter its source :

```
function f(){
    var gid=function(i){return document.getElementById(i);};
    var product_id=gid("one").value;
    var version_id=gid("two").value;
    var arch_id=gid("three").value;

    if(product_id==='default' || version_id ==='default' || arch_id === 'default'){
        return;
    }

    $("#idOfTheNewImageTag").prop('src', product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.jpg');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling your code in, I can see that it replaces the current browser URL with the url that you generate (not opening another browser tab or window) - so the browser (chrome in my case) navigates away to the URL that you generate (which is exactly what *location.replace* is intended to do).

Do you mean that you want to load the image into another tag / div / span / image?

---

To load a new div / image (using jquery):

```
$("<div>").appendTo("body").load(newUrl);
```

or

```
$("<img>").attr("src", newUrl).appendTo("body");
```

or

using raw js:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", newUrl);
```

(use insertBefore etc to move the element around in the dom)

HTH!

Comment: Yes, i want to load it in to a div on the same page.

Comment: Ah - in that case you could inject a new div/img into the document and "load" the img into it.  Will update answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try using link

```
window.open('images/' +product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.jpg','_self');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, @Zeratops' answer will require JQuery to do job, this code below won't.

```
function f(){
var gid=function(i){return document.getElementById(i);};
var product_id=gid("one").value;
var version_id=gid("two").value;
var arch_id=gid("three").value;

if(product_id==='default' || version_id ==='default' || arch_id === 'default'){
    return;
}

gid("idOfTheNewImageTag").src='images/'+product_id + '_' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.jpg';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the new div in html code. Demo in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cm8x9ue9/1/)

```
<div id="img"> </div>
```

Include the `Jquery` and use this function.

```
 function f(){
    var gid=function(i){return document.getElementById(i);};
    var product_id=gid("one").value;
    var version_id=gid("two").value;
    var arch_id=gid("three").value;
    if(product_id==='default' || version_id ==='default' || arch_id === 'default'){return;}       

     var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3css.gif')
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#img").html(img);
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine. The only thing is that when I make a new selection a new picture ends up next to the first selection. Is there a way to just make it change to the new picture?

Comment: @user1301000: Check the updated result. corrected it.